# Function type mismatch

Tags: haskell, recursion, type-mismatch

I have a function with function type :

```
newtonRootSequence' :: Double -> Double -> [Double]
```

and function definition:

```
newtonRootSequence' xn d = [(xn + (d * (1/xn))) div 2] ++ newtonRootSequence' ((xn + (d * (1/xn))) div 2) d
```

upon receiving two values xn and d it should calculate the results for the given function

```
[(xn + (d * (1/xn))) div 2]
```

But for some reason on launch the compilator is not accepting the function with an error:

> Couldnt match expected type '(Integer->Integer->Integer->) ->Integer
>   ->Double with actual type double the function (xn + (d * (1/xn))) div 2) is applied to two arguments

This error occurs to the part where I try to send the result of the equation into the recursive step

```
++ newtonRootSequence' ((xn + (d * (1/xn))) div 2) d
```

Comment: If you want to use `div` as an infix function, you need to use backquotes, i.e, `\`div\``

Comment: Moreover div accepts only Integrals.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments:

- if you want to use `div` as an infix function, you have to enclose it in backticks
- `div` is for integral division with truncation towards negative infinity, not for dividing `Double`

These two points are the cause for your error message.

To divide `Doubles`, use the `/` operator like you already did in your expression `1/xn`.

With this your code should work. For clarity it could be transformed:

1. Extract the duplicated expression to compute the next `xn` in the sequence into a `where` clause. The expression can also be slightly simplified. Adding a single element in front of a list can simply be done with the cons operator `(:)`:

   ```
   newtonRootSequence' xn d = xn' : newtonRootSequence' xn' d
       where xn' = (xn + (d / xn)) / 2
   ```
2. You could use `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]` from the Prelude to separate the computation for a single step from the generation of the list of intermediate steps (note the flipped arguments):

   ```
   sequenceStep :: Double -> Double -> Double
   sequenceStep s xn = (xn + (s / xn)) / 2

   newtonRootSequence' :: Double -> Double -> [Double]
   newtonRootSequence' s x0 = iterate (sequenceStep s) x0
   ```